# updating graph with multiple programs automatically prepends the location of turtle file to previous URIs

Tags: python, ontology, rdflib

`sosa_sensor.py` is supposed to create the turtle file and `update_sosa_sensor.py` is supposed to update the same file, the turtle file is stored at the same location as both the programs. My codes and turtle files are as follows:

**sosa_sensor.py**

```
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, BNode, RDF,URIRef
from rdflib import Namespace

data={'bn': 'Bhubaneswar/IIIT/iotlab/temperature','rt': 'oic.temperature.rt','id': 'xme2345','e':{'n':'temperature','u':'degC','v':'22'}}

SOSA = Namespace("http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/")
g = Graph()

g.bind('sosa',SOSA)
sensor=URIRef('sensor/'+data['id'])
obs=URIRef('observation/'+data['id'])

g.add((sensor,RDF.type,SOSA['Sensor']))
g.add((sensor,SOSA["observes"],obs))
g.add((obs,RDF.type,SOSA['Observation']))
g.add((obs,SOSA['madeBySensor'],sensor))
g.add((obs,SOSA['observedProperty'],URIRef(data['bn'])))
g.add((obs,SOSA['hasSimpleResult'],Literal(data['e']['v']+" "+data['e']['u'])))
g.serialize("temp_sensor.ttl", format="turtle")
```

after executing the above the turtle file created is as follows:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<observation/xme2345> a sosa:Observation ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "22 degC" ;
    sosa:madeBySensor <sensor/xme2345> ;
    sosa:observedProperty <Bhubaneswar/IIIT/iotlab/temperature> .

<sensor/xme2345> a sosa:Sensor ;
    sosa:observes <observation/xme2345> .
```

**update_sosa_sensor.py**

```
from rdflib import Graph,URIRef,Namespace,RDF,Literal
g=Graph()
g.parse("temp_sensor.ttl",format="turtle")

data={'bn': 'Bhubaneswar/IIIT/iotlab/humidity','rt': 'oic.humidity.rt','id': 'bxe345','e':{'n':'temperature','u':'%','v':'50'}}

sen=URIRef(data['bn'].split('/')[-1]+'sensor'+'/'+data['id'])
obs=URIRef('observation'+'/'+data['id'])

SOSA = Namespace("http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/")
g.bind('sosa',SOSA)


g.add((sen,RDF.type,SOSA['Sensor']))
g.add((sen,SOSA["observes"],obs))
g.add((sen,SOSA["observes"],obs))
g.add((obs,RDF.type,SOSA['Observation']))
g.add((obs,SOSA['madeBySensor'],sen))
g.add((obs,SOSA['observedProperty'],URIRef(data['bn'])))
g.add((obs,SOSA['hasSimpleResult'],Literal(data['e']['v']+" "+data['e']['u'])))
g.serialize("temp_sensor.ttl", format="turtle")
```

after executing the above the turtle file is updated as follows:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<file:///home/pratik/iotprojects/random_programs/project_implementation/observation/xme2345> a sosa:Observation ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "22 degC" ;
    sosa:madeBySensor <file:///home/pratik/iotprojects/random_programs/project_implementation/sensor/xme2345> ;
    sosa:observedProperty <file:///home/pratik/iotprojects/random_programs/project_implementation/Bhubaneswar/IIIT/iotlab/temperature> .

<file:///home/pratik/iotprojects/random_programs/project_implementation/sensor/xme2345> a sosa:Sensor ;
    sosa:observes <file:///home/pratik/iotprojects/random_programs/project_implementation/observation/xme2345> .

<humiditysensor/bxe345> a sosa:Sensor ;
    sosa:observes <observation/bxe345> .

<observation/bxe345> a sosa:Observation ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "50 %" ;
    sosa:madeBySensor <humiditysensor/bxe345> ;
    sosa:observedProperty <Bhubaneswar/IIIT/iotlab/humidity> .
```

when `update_sosa_sensor.py` is run it prepends the **path of the location of turtle file** to the old URIs which were already present in the graph, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Why do not use HTTP URIs? Or maybe SPARQL Update query would help you.

Comment: Thank you for the clue, since these resources are to be hosted on a CoAP server so i used coap uri, and it worked